# String of type mm:ss:SSS to LocalTime Kotlin/Java

Tags: java, kotlin, java-time

I have a time string `03:02:111` which is of pattern `mm:ss:SSS`. I would like to transform this into a LocalTime object.

*mm -> minutes*

*ss -> seconds*

*SSS -> mills*

**Simple example:**

```kotlin
val time = "03:02:111"
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm:ss:SSS")
val convertedTime = LocalTime.parse(time, formatter)
print(convertedTime.toString())
```

I get the following exception:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '03:02:111' could not be
> parsed: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor:
> {MicroOfSecond=111000, MilliOfSecond=111, NanoOfSecond=111000000,
> SecondOfMinute=2, MinuteOfHour=3},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed

Can someone explain why this is not working? I also checked the pattern twice.

Comment: As an aside, a format like `mm:ss:SSS` is non-[standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) and likely to be confusing; milliseconds are normally preceded by a `.`, and so times in this format could be easily mistaken for `HH:mm:ss`. Of course, this may be a fixed requirement; but if not, you might consider changing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have no definition of the hour. This means you have to build a smarter formatter, telling it which hour should be the default:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val time = "03:02:111"
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("mm:ss:SSS")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        .toFormatter()
    val convertedTime = LocalTime.parse(time, formatter)
    print(convertedTime.toString())
}
```

Of course, this will only work as long as the minutes are smaller than 60. If you don't have this guarantee, then you would need another approach.